# Run another textViewDidChange

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview

If I run the `textViewDidChange` function in the UITextView's extension, I can not use `textViewDidChange` in other classes.

Please tell me the solution.

It is the code as follows.
(It has been simplified.)

```
extension UITextView: UITextViewDelegate {
    initValue(){
        //Start this method at first.
        self.delegate = self
    }

    //1. If already set this method in this extension
    public func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
        print("Do something!!")
    }
}


class A: UITextViewDelegate{
    @IBOutlet weak var textView: UITextView!

    func initValue(){
        textView.delegate = self
    }

    //2. This method don't move
    func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
        print("Nein!! wan can't do anything!!")
    }
}
```

Comment: try `override func textViewDidChange()`

Comment: Thanks for comments. i added to class A.(override func textViewDidChange(_ te...), but Error displayed that "Method does not override any method from its superclass". Can i fix this?

Comment: Off the wall idea below. I think it will solve your problem. I've never done it but if I understand how it all works, that should do the trick.

Comment: Why are you creating a `UITextView` extension that sets itself as its own delegate? What benefit are you trying to achieve with this extension?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Define the method with a closure like this :

```
func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView, _  completion: (() -> Swift.Void)? = nil){
    completion?()
    return
}
```

> Subscribe to the notifications in your `viewDidLoad()` like :

```
textField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(doChanges(_:)), for: .editingChanged)
```

> And add the function to that viewController that lets you do stuff on completion

```
@objc func doChanges() {
    textFieldDidChange(self.textField) { 
        //doCustomWorkHere
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you jake, I will try this :)

Comment: Now that I think about it. That is only really necessary if you have a default functionality that `textFieldDidChange` will call in the extension. That way it will call it's default functionality and you can add to it in the completion block if  you want to.

Comment: I updated the `addTarget` and `doChanges` to Swift 3